# Screen escapes differently when called from bash

Tags: bash, shell, prolog, swi-prolog, gnu-screen

I have a long running server process called ROBUST, which has a console. We run it in a screen and attach to manually manipulate the server (it's a virtual world server).

I have a web app (in prolog) that occasionally needs to add a user. ROBUST has a couple programmatic interfaces that are both awkward for various reasons. So I'm trying to just
shell out, attach a screen with -X, and do the equivilent of typing

create user SomeUser SomeName SomePass somebody@somewhere.com
newline

on the console.  This line

`screen -S ROBUST -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "create user SomeUser SomeName SomePass somebody@somewhere.com ^M"`'

works

but when I put it in this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -S ROBUST -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "create user $1 $2 $3 $4 ^M"'
```

it doesn't.
Attaching to the ROBUST console with another terminal and watching, it thinks the line ends at create user

I've tried every scheme I can think of for escaping the various single and double quotes, but at this point am stumped.

later comment:

I got around the need for bash script by figuring out the prolog process_create syntax

```
?- process_create(path(screen), ['-S', 'ROBUST', '-p', '0', '-X', eval, 'stuff "create user Manny Muncher somepass somebody@uh.edu^M"'], []).
```

Comment: Do you need `eval` at all? Why can't you just `stuff`?

Comment: Yes - the eval is needed to convert ^M to a newline.  Doing it without the eval puts a literal ^M on the end of the line.

Comment: @Anniepoo: I think there's something wrong here. `eval` isn't supposed to convert `^M` to a carriage-return.

Answer (score 3):

```
screen -S ROBUST -p 0 -X eval 'stuff "create user $1 $2 $3 $4 ^M"'
```

Strings are not expanded inside ' ' . You must use " " for bash to expand $1, etc.

Comment: That was my first instinct too, but it's actually **not** true when used with `eval`. Try the following in a script: `echo '$1 $2 $3'; eval 'echo "$1 $2 $3"'`. provide `a b c` as argument to the script on your cmdline and you should see: `$1 $2 $3` followed by `a b c`

Comment: @sampson-chen: That's because `eval` is a built-in Bash function, so when you write `eval 'echo "$1 $2 $3"'` in a Bash script, it's run within Bash, which has full knowledge of what `$1` and `$2` and `$3` are. But as soon as you pass that as an argument to `screen` (or any other external command), you're no longer running within the original Bash instance, so the `$1` and `$2` and `$3` become unset, and get replaced with *nothing*.